# Concatinating rows in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I have a many to many relationship in postgres that is books and authors. Authors can have many books and books can have many authors.
I also have a join table that just contains the author_id and book_id.
For simplicity's sake, just assume my authors table has an id, full_name and my books table has an id, title.
Here is some sample data.

```
authors
id|full_name
------------
 1|Ben Hernandez
 2|Another Person

books
id|title
------------
 1|How to be terrible at SQL

book_author
book_id|author_id
-----------------
      1|1
      1|2
```

What I would like is a query that returns something like this

```
title                    |authors
---------------------------------
How to be terrible at SQL|Ben Hernandez,Another Person
```

Right now I am selecting title,author using joins on all three tables which is giving me this:

```
title                    |full_name
---------------------------------
How to be terrible at SQL|Ben Hernandez
How to be terrible at SQL|Another Person
```

and I am using javascript to build an array of authors with the results, which is working fine but if someone has a way to do this in sql, I would love to see it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Did some more googling and finally figured out this:

```
select books.title, string_agg(authors.full_name, ', ') from books
  inner join book_author on book_author.book_id = books.id
  inner join authors on book_author.author_id = authors.id
group by books.title;
```